# MenuItem subMenu property: how to assign it?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I read MenuItem documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-menuitem.html

MenuItem has property subMenu but this property is read only. And I cannot find any other properties or methods to add sub menu to MenuItem.

How to add sub menu to MenuItem?

I need to handle MenuItem signal `triggered` and have submenu simultaneously. So using Menu class instead of MenuItem is not a solution of my problem because it does not have signal `triggered`.

Answer (score 1):

from: https://www3.sra.co.jp/qt/relation/doc/qtlabsplatform/qml-qt-labs-platform-menu.html#submenus

To create submenus, declare a Menu as a child of another Menu:

```
Menu {
title: qsTr("Edit")

Menu {
    title: qsTr("Advanced")

    MenuItem {
        text: qsTr("Auto-indent Selection")
        onTriggered: autoIndentSelection()
    }

    MenuItem {
        text: qsTr("Rewrap Paragraph")
        onTriggered: rewrapParagraph()
    }
}
}
```

[image: SubMenu]

Comment: Is this child menu a MenuItem instance? I need to access to MenuItem members which are absent in Menu class.

Comment: No, it is not a MenuItem, only from type Menu